# How to run a processor only when ahother proccessor has finished its execution?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm migrating a table (2 millions of rows) from DB2 to SQL Server. I'm using the next flow:

1. ExecuteSQL (to select records from the Db2 table).
2. SplitAvro (to split the records. I configured it with Output Size = 1 to control the case that if one fails the rest is inserted without problems.
3. PutDataBaseRecord (to insert the records in the SQL Server table).
4. ExecuteSQL (I need to call a stored procedure that executes update sentences against the same table that PutDataBaseRecord is working to).

The problem is the second ExecuteSQL is running before PutDataBaseRecord complete the insertion of all records.

How can I tell nifi to run that processor only when the other one finishes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

After PutDatabaseRecord you can use MergeContent in Defragment mode to undo the split operation performed by SplitAvro. This way a single flow file will come out of MergeContent only when all splits have been seen, and at that point you know its time to for the second ExecuteSQL to run.

Comment: Thanks Bryan for your answer! I tried with MergeContent but another problem arose. It happens that some records failed in the insert and for that MergeContent never runs. How can you handle this?

Comment: you would need to route the failure relationship to merge content as well, since all the splits are combination of success + failure coming out of PutDatabaseRecord

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @bryan-bende is great, as it is simple and elegant. If that doesn't work for some reason, you could also look at Wait/Notify. Having said that, Bryan's answer is simpler and probably more robust.